# How do I prove that for any set $A$, $|A| < |\mathbb{N}|$ implies that $A$ is finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's what I've tried so far.

Let $A$ be a set and suppose $|A| < |\mathbb{N}|$. By the definition of less than for cardinalities (I'm reading out of Hrbacek's Introduction to Set Theory), this means that there exists a one-to-one function $f$ from $A$ onto a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, but there does **not** exist a one-to-one function from $A$ onto $\mathbb{N}$ itself.

In the book, finite is defined as in bijection with a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The natural numbers are defined in a weird way:

$$0 = \varnothing$$

$$1 = \{0\} = \{\varnothing\}$$

$$2 = \{0,1\}$$

$$3 = \{0,1,2\}$$

... and so on *ad infinitum*.

My intuition is this: I want to show that $A$ is in one-to-one correspondence with a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and once I've done this it's trivial to show that $A$ is finite itself (the composition of bijections is a bijection, so $A$ is in bijection with some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and we're done). I just have no idea how to find the correspondence with a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

If I show that any infinite (infinite is simply defined as not finite) subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ itself, this would work ...

Comment: This has been asked before. What you want to show is that for any infinite set $A$, $\aleph_0\leqslant \# A$. This can be proven using the axiom of choice.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff what is $\#A$? EDIT: Are you sure this requires the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: Consider the following argument: since $A\neq \varnothing$, there is $x_0\in A$. Since $A$ is infinite, there is $x_1\in A\smallsetminus x_0$. Since $A$ is infinite, there is $x_2\in A\smallsetminus \{x_0,x_1\}$. Since $A$ is infinite, $\ldots$. Then $x_i\longleftrightarrow i$ is a bijection, i.e. there is a subset $A'\subseteq A$ equipotent with $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Then there is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ via the function that takes $\{x_0, x_1 ... x_n\}$ to $n$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Okay I think this works, the recursion part seems a bit non-rigorous but it makes complete intuitive sense to me

Comment: More formally, let $f$ be a choice function for $A$, and consider the function $g$ from the collection $C$ of *finite* subsets of $A$ to itself that sends $S$ to $S\cup \{f(A-S)\}$. That is, $g$ adds to $S$ the element we choose from $A-S$. By the recursion theorem there exists a unique function $h:\Bbb N\to C$ for which $h(0)=\varnothing$ and $h(n+1)=g(h(n))=h(n)\cup \{f(A-h(n))\}$, which is simply iterating the process. Let $v:\Bbb N\to A$ be defined by $v(n)=f(A-h(n))$. This is the desired bijection.

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice. Without axiom of choice, you can prove that every subset of $\Bbb{N}$ is finite or countable.

Comment: I said it *can* be proven using the axiom of choice, I never said you *need* the axiom of choice, @VincentLuo. (" Are you sure this requires the Axiom of Choice?")

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Sure, but bringing choice into the argument is at least distracting.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071516/how-do-i-prove-that-for-any-set-a-a-mathbbn-implies-that-a-is-fi#comment2179277_1071516) seems classically clear and intuitive to me. I hope I didn't confuse anyone.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Sure, but I think the point of the question is that you can just define the bijection between $A$ and an initial segment of $\mathbb N$ without having to assume even the small amount of the axiom of choice that the argument you suggest requires. (In particular, your argument is not using the assumption that $A$ injects into $\mathbb N$. Of course, you can then invoke Bernstein-Cantor, but...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an infinite set of $A$ we can define an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb N$ by the inclusion mapping. define the injective map from $\mathbb N$ to $A$ where $1$ goes to the minimum element of $\mathbb A$, where $2$ goes to the minimum element of $A\setminus f(1)$ and in general map $n$ to the minimum element of $A\setminus \{f(i)|1\leq i\leq(n-1)\}$.

So if you have an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$

Comment: Oh, I thought I could do that, sorry I haven't taken set theory yet.

Comment: You can prove that $A$ can be well-ordered. Define the order $\prec$ over $A$ such that $x\prec y$ iff $i(x)<i(y)$, where $i$ is an injection from $A$ to $\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: I was just using the order on $\mathbb N$

Comment: $A$ is well ordered using the induced order from $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah, that what was I was thinking.

Comment: @JorgeFernández It was not clear to me what assumptions you were working with.

Comment: I also think I should add that the sets I am using are never empty, for if there would come a time where one of those sets was empty we could conclude the set was finite.

Comment: He's only assuming that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered. It works.

Comment: You can reorganize the presentation to avoid all this silly discussion about choice: You have an injection from $A$ into $\mathbb N$. Use it to define (pretty much following your outline) another injection from $A$ into $\mathbb N$, but now ensuring that the range is an initial segment.

Comment: I would love to see your answer on this, I have no background on set theory, all that I knew in my mind was Cantor Schroeder Bernestein and that $\mathbb N$ is well ordered. And I thought this was a neat idea. But I would really like to see an answer written by a pro.

Comment: You could even avoid Cantor-Bernstein by noting that the function mapping $f(n)$ to the minimum of $A\setminus\{f(i)\mid i<n\}$ is a bijection.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you that's sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:A \to \mathbb{N}$ be an injection.  Consider the following recursively defined function $g:D\subseteq \mathbb{N} \to A$:

$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
g(n) = \argmin_{a\in A\setminus\{g(k)|k<n\}}(f(a))
$$

Notice that $g$ is a bijection from its domain of definition $D$ to $A$, so $D$ cannot equal all of $\mathbb{N}$ (since $|A| < |\mathbb{N}|$).  Therefore there exists some $n = \min(\mathbb{N}\setminus D)$.  Observe that $D = \{0, \ldots, n-1\} = n$.  So $g$ is a bijection from $n$ to $A$, so $A$ is finite.